# react-router-redux doesn't update page on location change

Tags: react-router, react-router-redux

I haven't had much luck using the redux version of react-router. When I add a product to the cart, the location *does* change, but the page doesn't update.

This is my setup so far. Everything else works with the new router adding items to the cart comes back from the REST server successfully. However, using `push` in my actions file doesn't update the page.

**index.js**

```js
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from 'redux';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';
import createHistory from 'history/createBrowserHistory';
import { ConnectedRouter, routerMiddleware } from 'react-router-redux';
import reducers from './reducers';
import App from './components/app';

const history = createHistory();
const store = createStore(
    reducers,
    applyMiddleware(routerMiddleware(history), thunk)
);

ReactDOM.render(
    <Provider store={store}>
        <ConnectedRouter history={history}>
            <App />
        </ConnectedRouter>
    </Provider>,
    document.getElementById('app')
);
```

**app.js**

```js
import React from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Link, Route } from 'react-router-dom';

import Cart from '../containers/cart';
import Home from './home';
import Checkout from '../containers/checkout';
import Products from '../containers/products';


const App = () => (
    <Router>
        <div className="app">
            <Route exact={true} path="/" component={Home} />
            <Route path="/cart" component={Cart} />
            <Route path="/checkout" component={Checkout} />
            <Route path="/products/:id/:url_title" component={Products} />
        </div>
    </Router>
);

export default App;
```

**./reducers**

```js
import { reducer as FormReducer } from 'redux-form';
import { combineReducers } from 'redux';
import { routerReducer } from 'react-router-redux';

const rootReducer = combineReducers({
    router: routerReducer,
    other: otherReducers
});

export default rootReducer;
```

**./actions**

```js
import { push } from 'react-router-redux';

export function addProduct(props) {
    return dispatch =>
        axios.post(`${ROOT_URL}/api`, props, config)
            .then(response => {
                dispatch(push('/cart'));
            })
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try [connecting](https://github.com/reactjs/react-redux/blob/master/docs/api.md#connectmapstatetoprops-mapdispatchtoprops-mergeprops-options) `app.js` to the redux store and injecting the `router` prop via `mapStateToProps`. Even though you don't explicitly use the prop, your component should now re-render itself and its children whenever that prop changes.

`react-router` also offers a [`withRouter`](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/packages/react-router/docs/api/withRouter.md) Higher Order Component to do something similar. However, I've had issues getting it to work in applications that use `shouldComponentUpdate` at multiple levels of a component tree.